# PlayIn Packets for TabComplete Bukkit 1.8 R3

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to modify the TabComplete Action in Minecraft on my server (version 1.8 R3).
I want to edit the tab auto complete pool with a pool from me and I did that using protocollib.
The Problem is, the pool should be fit to the last tooken of the sentence, typed in to chat. Otherwise it is not a TabComplete but just a showing of all options rather than adjusting the pool to what option you seek.

So for example: 
I type `/test t[TAB]` and the Pool is something like that: `test, urf, halo tinker`.
What should happen is that those options are showing:

```
test, tinker
```

what really show up is:

```
test, urf, halo, tinker
```

because I only can replace the pool in the tabcompletepacket. but not get the actually `t[tab]` which I need to adjust my pool.
Which packet gives those informations to the server?

//EDIT
No point of leaving this as unanwsered. My problems was, that I did not saw the PlayInTabComplete-Function which actually gives you the String needed.
By connection those two packets via a variable it is very easy to edit the pool as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example with /test, is test your command? If it is so you can easily add a tabcomple function to the command. There you can also check all arguments given and answer with a list.

Comment: Well no, not really. There is not a tab-complete function in the PlayerCommandPreprocess Event, which is used to register Commands.
The answer is very simple. There actually exists a PlayInTabComplete and a PLayOutTabComplete- Packet which gives you the string and which gives a Strin back to the player. I just did not saw it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the PlayerComandPreprocessEvent instead of registering a event with "plugin.getCommand("name").setExecutor(..."
If you use a class implements commandexecutor, you can implement the method onTabComplete

Comment: Yeah well, I know that, The CommandExectuer only fifts for that special command. So if the tabcomplete has to be changed for commands from other plugins, it wouldn't work. (thats why I talked about the CommandPreProcessEvent ).
But your answer doesn't have to do something with the question